# Determining if $\{x,y \mid x=y^2\}$ is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given an equation, $\{x,y \mid x=y^2\}$ is this a subspace? My argument is this is not a subspace, because $(4,2)$ and $(9,3)$ both satisfies the equation but the linear combination of the two vectors $(13,5)$ does not satisfy the given expression. Am I correct in this sense?

Comment: A (linear) subspace must contain the line through the origin and any point. The point $(1,1)$ is in the above, but $(2,2)$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is correct. For determining whether a given space is subspace for the vector space or not, you must satisfy the two basic conditions:

1. Closed under vector addition
2. Closed under scalar multiplication

Since the given equation does not satisfy the first condition, it is futile to check for the second one. Hence, the given equation does not form a subspace.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. Can you figure out what kind of equation will give you a subspace? (Hint: what does a subspace of the plane look like geometrically?)

Comment: Like x-2y=0 ? Can I say that the plane looks flat geometrically? I know it sounds stupid, but have no idea how it look like.

Comment: @George Yes like $x-2y=0$ which defines a linear subspace. You're probably overthinking it because I'm pretty sure you know the shape of that curve.

Comment: X=y^2 is like a hyperbola?? Whereas x-2y =0 is a flat surface??

Comment: @George quite.  All subpsaces of $\Bbb R^n$ will always be either the trivial subspace containing the origin alone, lines passing through the origin, planes passing through the origin, or hyperplanes passing through the origin.  (*the origin, lines, and planes are all just lower dimensional hyperplanes and so can be omitted from the list if you don't mind*).